# ValidationError pass multi level dictionary insted of single dict

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to raise a ValidationError with nested dict of errors?. For example:

```
raise ValidationError({
                "index_errors": {"index1": {
                    "test_con": "Error text example",
                    "test_con2": "Error text example2"
                }}
            }
```

I am getting 'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'error_list'

Answer (score -1):

You should put error info in lists, something like

```
raise ValidationError({"index_error": {"index1": {"test_con": ["Error text"]}}}
```